# Connection reset on uploading files greater than 70kb with angular as frontend and Flask as backend

Tags: angular, python-3.x, flask, file-upload

I am uploading a file from angular and taking it in flask API. When I upload files larger than 70KB, I get error on frontend as connection reset with error code 0

I haven't set max_content_length in flask still somehow it is automatically setting limit. I don't want to set limit over size right now.

```
@app.route('/route/ , methods=['POST']):
def fileUpload():
    file = request.files['file']
```

error in backend:flask

```
"POST /sendHash HTTP/1.1" 308 -
```

error in frontend:Angular 7

```
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Comment: I am using memory to store file. is it causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume there's a default file upload limit, which you might be encountering. Did you try increasing the limit as shown in [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads)?

This should increase it to 16M

```py
from flask import Flask, Request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

Comment: according to docs, by default there is no limit.    https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads